# Create derrived collection of ViewModels with DynamicData which updates existing item instead of creating a new one on source item change

Tags: c#, system.reactive, dynamic-data, reactiveui, reactive

For example, I have an observable of some collections which indicates statuses of objects (I get it periodically through REST API).

```
class User
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Status { get; }
}

IObservable<User> source;
```

I want to create a `DynamicCache` object and update it each time the `source` gives me a new result. So I wrote:

```
var models = new SourceCache<User,int>(user => user.Id);
models.Connect()
      .Transform(u => new UserViewModel() {...})
      ...
      .Bind(out viewModels)
      .Subscribe();

source.Subscribe(ul => models.EditDiff(ul, (a, b) => a.Status == b.Status));
```

But now every time a user changes its status, `.Transform(...)` method creates a new instance of `UserViewModel`, which isn't the desired behaviour.

Can I somehow determine a rule of updating existing ViewModel's properties (in the derived collection) when source item with the same Id is changing instead of creating a new one every time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is you need to create a custom operator. I have posted a gist here [TransformWithInlineUpdate](https://gist.github.com/RolandPheasant/3bba5e32f2eefb70c538ce4acabf17cb) which you can copy into your solution. Example usage is:

```
var users = new SourceCache<User, int>(user => user.Id);

var transformed =  users.Connect()
    .TransformWithInlineUpdate(u => new UserViewModel(u), (previousViewModel, updatedUser) =>
        {
            previousViewModel.User = updatedUser;
        });
```

For completeness of the answer, here is the code:

```
    public static IObservable<IChangeSet<TDestination, TKey>> TransformWithInlineUpdate<TObject, TKey, TDestination>(this IObservable<IChangeSet<TObject, TKey>> source,
        Func<TObject, TDestination> transformFactory,
        Action<TDestination, TObject> updateAction = null)
    {
        return source.Scan((ChangeAwareCache<TDestination, TKey>)null, (cache, changes) =>
            {
                //The change aware cache captures a history of all changes so downstream operators can replay the changes
                if (cache == null)
                    cache = new ChangeAwareCache<TDestination, TKey>(changes.Count);

                foreach (var change in changes)
                {
                    switch (change.Reason)
                    {
                        case ChangeReason.Add:
                            cache.AddOrUpdate(transformFactory(change.Current), change.Key);
                            break;
                        case ChangeReason.Update:
                        {
                            if (updateAction == null) continue;

                            var previous = cache.Lookup(change.Key)
                                .ValueOrThrow(()=> new MissingKeyException($"{change.Key} is not found."));
                            //callback when an update has been received
                            updateAction(previous, change.Current);

                            //send a refresh as this will force downstream operators to filter, sort, group etc
                            cache.Refresh(change.Key);
                        }
                            break;
                        case ChangeReason.Remove:
                            cache.Remove(change.Key);
                            break;
                        case ChangeReason.Refresh:
                            cache.Refresh(change.Key);
                            break;
                        case ChangeReason.Moved:
                            //Do nothing !
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return cache;
                
            }).Select(cache => cache.CaptureChanges()); //invoke capture changes to return the changeset
    }
```

**Update**: this has been included in the library.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted to.

I think it's a quite common situation and I think it would be a good idea to add it right into the library.

Comment: @Paboka Yes, I agree.

Comment: Should it be added to DynamicData.Snippets as an example? @Roland Pheasant